# eclipse drag and drop on text editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a requirement for creating drag and drop plugin (just like window builder) where I have a view with buttons in it. And if I drag a button and drop from the view I should be able to generate some code on the java text editor.

I want to create this plugin for generating the code. I don't have any knowledge in Eclipse plugin development. I have gone through http://www.eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html, but I am not sure where to store the code to be generated. Will it be somewhere in a text file, or somewhere else?

Comment: Perhaps the [template editor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIWorkbenchPage.html) has information about creating/modifying existing documents in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

A site from 2001 will not help you alot. Today PDE does not need much experience, its self-describing.

1. Go "File"->"New"->"Others"
2. Choose "Plug-in Development" -> "Plug-in Project"
3. Enter a name, press Next,Next
4. Choose the Template "Plug-in with a View" or "Plug-in with an editor" (what you prefer)

Read and write.

Answer (score 0):

AS per my understaning you want to develop graphical editor for some domain language. Options you have for this

1. Eclipse GEF
2. Eclipse GMF
3. Eclipse Graphiti

basically code will be stored in same file but you will have graphical editor.

PS: Developing graphical editors can be pretty tricky :)

Comment: can you elaborate more on this.